# HTTP Spoofing?

Tags: php, http, spoofing

I have two questions:

1) In PHP, when a programmer uses the "REMOTE_ADDR" variable to get the IP address of the web client, that IP address is taken from a field in the HTTP header? Or from where?

2) If the IP address of the client is taken from the HTTP headers, can a web client "spoof" or "change" the HTTP headers to hide his real IP address?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

`REMOTE_ADDR` is taken from the TCP/IP connection and it's *very hard* to spoof.

It could be inaccurate though, if your server is behind a reverse proxy. In that case you'd have to read `X-Forwarded-For` header, which *can* be spoofed easily if your proxy doesn't always override it.

Answer (score 4):

**$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] :** As said is taking the IP from the IP socket in the TCP connection... The way to spoof your real IP is easy using a remote server for example: 'TOR network'.

**Example:**
If I want to send a request to the site server (but I need to spoof my IP) I use:

```
<?php

$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '9051';
$auth = 'PASSWORD';
$command = 'signal NEWNYM';
$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$error_number,$err_string,10);
if(!$fp) { echo "ERROR: $error_number : $err_string";
    return false;
          } else {
                     fwrite($fp,"AUTHENTICATE \"".$auth."\"\n");
                     $received = fread($fp,512);
                     fwrite($fp,$command."\n");
                     $received = fread($fp,512);
                 }
 fclose($fp);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://whatismyip.org"); //ipimg.php
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $response;
?>
```

This code demonstrate how I'm spoofing my IP using a TOR service that is using SOCKS5 / SOCKS4
to send requests to another server without using my real IP.
I'm testing it with whatismyip.org to see the IP change.

Have fun.

Comment: Set the PASSWORD and the port number. I am getting nothing. Page tries to load for a while and then dies. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the Tor server? Make sure Tor uses port 9050, Make sure your php is set to expose errors. Now try again and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

1) `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` comes straight from the TCP connection.

2) `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` can only be spoofed using a man in the middle attack on a non-SSL TCP connection (the SSL handshake has some protections against IP spoofing).

2) `$_SERVER` variables which come from HTTP headers are prefixed with `HTTP_` and yes, if they contain IP addresses, they can be spoofed trivially by the caller. You should never trust `$_SERVER["HTTP_*"]` variables which contain IP addresses.